# Trying port Obj-C code to Swift that checks if keys exist in dict and values have correct type

Tags: objective-c, swift, foundation

Okay, here is some Objective C code I've been using in the past to quickly check if a dictionary contains certain key/value pairs and if the values are of the right type (have the expected class).

First I need a little helper class:

```
@interface TypeCheck : NSObject
    @property NSString * name;
    @property Class type;
@end

@implementation TypeCheck
    + (instancetype)typeCheckWitName:(NSString *)name type:(Class)type {
        TypeCheck * tc = [[self alloc] init];
        tc.name = name;
        tc.type = type;
        return tc;
    }
@end
```

And then I can define keys and types like this:

```
NSArray<TypeCheck *> * model = @[
    [TypeCheck typeCheckWitName:@"firstName" type:[NSString class]],
    [TypeCheck typeCheckWitName:@"lastName" type:[NSString class]],
    [TypeCheck typeCheckWitName:@"age" type:[NSNumber class]],
    [TypeCheck typeCheckWitName:@"image" type:[NSImage class]]
    // ... Many more follow ...
];
```

I was able to use structs for all that prior to ARC but with ARC the compiler doesn't like objects in structs, so I now use objects for everything. The final check code just looks like this:

```
for (TypeCheck * typeCheck in model) {
    id value = dict[typeCheck.name];
    if (!value) {
        // BAD... Value must be there
        // Throw error
        return;
    }
    if (![value isKindOfClass:typeCheck.type]) {
        // BAD... Value must be of right type
        // Throw error
        return;
    }
    // Do something with value
}
```

This used to be pretty nice code IMHO. Gets even nicer if you use a C function to create the TypeCheck objects:

```
#define TypeString [NSString class]
#define TypeNumber [NSNumber class]
#define TypeImage  [NSImage class]

static TypeCheck * makeTypeCheck ( NSString * name, Class type ) {
    return [TypeCheck typeCheckWitName:name type:type];
}
```

And then:

```
NSArray<TypeCheck *> * model = @[
    makeTypeCheck(@"firstName", TypeString),
    makeTypeCheck(@"lastName", TypeString),
    makeTypeCheck(@"age", TypeNumber),
    makeTypeCheck(@"image", TypeImage)
    // ... and so on ...
```

One could even make `makeTypeCheck` a macro.

And now I'm trying to do the same or similar in Swift... and I fail horribly! I tried with a struct but how can I store class types there? I don't want to use `Any` as a type qualifier. Then I tried with a generic struct, like `struct TypeCheck<T>` so I could set the type, but I cannot put multiple of these into a single array as when `T` is different, as these are effectively different types (and again, I don't want to use `Array<Any>` despite that how can I cast? I cannot cast to `TypeCheck` without a generic type). I don't have to use a struct, an object will be fine but that doesn't really solve any of my problems. I cannot believe that this is so hard to do in Swift. I'm not really a Swift expert yet, so I guess i must be missing something important here.

Answer (score 1):

While Obj-C was good at dynamic type inspection, Swift is much better of you allow the compiler to do the type checking at compile time. Since I don't know what your specific use case is, I'd encourage you to look for a more Swifty way to do what you want instead of just converting Obj-C to Swift. But since I don't know your use case, I'll just answer your question as written.

---

The only way I could get something like you describe was to make the struct conform to a protocol. Then when you put it in an array, you set the arrays type to contain instances of the protocol.

```
protocol TypeCheckable {
    var name: String { get }

    func matches(thing: Any) -> Bool
}

struct TypeCheck<T>: TypeCheckable {
    let name: String

    init(name: String, type: T.Type) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func matches(thing: Any) -> Bool {
        return thing is T
    }
}

let array: [TypeCheckable] = [
    TypeCheck(name: "test", type: String.self),
    TypeCheck(name: "other", type: Int.self)
]
```

Comment: You define `TypeCheck<T> as generic` but I never see you setting the type (e.g. you don't write `TypeCheck<String>(...)`). So will the compiler automatically get the type, just because I pass it to `init`? Otherwise very good answer! The use case is simple: I get a dictionary, that dictionary may have over 60 entries and I must not use anything from it, unless know for sure all mandatory entries are there and have correct values. That's the use case. And no, I don't need to actually use all values, I only need a few of them. Writing 60+ `guard` lines would have worked, but... ugly.

Comment: The compiler gets it from the type passed into the init method. You could set it up to allow `TypeCheck<String>(name: "Thing")` but I prefer not having to use the angled brackets.

Comment: I see... didn't expect the compiler to be that clever :) Yeah, having all the generics conform to the same protocol, so they can be added to a single array and then be used without additional casting is something I definitely didn't think of. Now that I know it, this totally makes sense of course. I still need to get used to all these new techniques you can use in Swift ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you define this:

```
typealias TypeChecker = ([String: AnyObject]) -> Bool

struct makeTypeCheck<T> {
    let name: String
    func checker() -> TypeChecker {
        return { (dict: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool in
            guard let v = dict[self.name] else {
                return false
            }
            if let _ = v as? T {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}

func checkDictionary(dict: [String: AnyObject], model: [TypeChecker]) -> Bool {
    for m in model {
        if !m(dict) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

This test passes

```
func testChecker() {
    let model = [
        makeTypeCheck<String>(name: "firstName").checker(),
        makeTypeCheck<Int>(name: "age").checker(),
    ]

    XCTAssertTrue(checkDictionary(["firstName": "Jane", "age": 35], model: model))
    XCTAssertFalse(checkDictionary(["firstName": 21, "age": 35], model: model))
    XCTAssertFalse(checkDictionary(["age": 35], model: model))
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty interesting solution as well. Contrary tot he protocol approach, this is a more functional approach. So basically I create an array of function calls here, yet the compiler is doing most of the work (I just provide the pattern). Do you know if this will create really an own function for every key to check or are all functions of the same type (e.g. all `<String>` functions) actually shared, after all they are identical except for the name argument. Just curious.

Comment: There will only be one for each type in your generated code.  They are generated at compile-time. When I call the checker() function, it will generate a new closure (the name + function) object.